# Issue popToRootViewController when dismissing view controller

Tags: swift

**On dismiss of a .formsheet I need to perform a poptoviewcontroller currently I am presenting the view controller by doing the following:**

```
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "test") as! TestVC
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Attempting to dismiss and popToRootViewController underneath is not working**

```
    self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        print("Dismissing")
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    })
```

The dismiss is working, but it does not popToRootViewController.

Comment: When you're accessing the ````navigationController```` in your ````completion````, you're accessing the same ````navigationController```` you've just dismissed, and not the "root" one.

Comment: How can I access the navigation controller of the root?

Answer (score 0):

When you're accessing the `navigationController` in your `completion`, you're accessing the same `navigationController` you've just dismissed, and not the "root" one.

Here's one of the ways you can access the navigation controller you're interested in and pop to root from it:

```
let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    print("Dismissing")
    presentingVC?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
})
```